# Accessing Float samples of AVAudioPCMBuffer for processing

Tags: swift, audio, avfoundation, avaudioengine, avaudiopcmbuffer

I am trying to do some computation on the raw PCM samples of a mp3 files I'm playing with an AVAudioEngine graph.  I have a closure every 44100 samples that provides an `AVAudioPCMBuffer`.  It has a property `channelData` of type `UnsafePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>>?`.  I have not worked with pointers in Swift 3 and so I'm unclear how to access these Float values.

I have the following code but there are many issues:

```
audioPlayerNode.installTap(onBus: 0, 
                           bufferSize: 1024, 
                           format: audioPlayerNode.outputFormat(forBus: 0)) { (pcmBuffer, time) in

let numChans = Int(pcmBuffer.format.channelCount)
let frameLength = pcmBuffer.frameLength
     
if let chans = pcmBuffer.floatChannelData?.pointee {
    for a in 0..<numChans {   
        let samples = chans[a]// samples is type Float.  should be pointer to Floats.
        for b in 0..<flength {
            print("sample: \(b)") // should be samples[b] but that gives error as "samples" is Float
        }
    }
}
```

For instance, how do I iterate through the `UnsafeMutablePointer<Float`s which are `N` float pointers where `N` is the number of channels in the buffer.  I could not find discussion on accessing buffer samples in the Apple Docs on this Class.

I think the main problem is `let samples = chans[a]`.  Xcode says `chans` is of type `UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>`.  But that should be NumChannels worth of those pointers.  Which is why I use `a in 0..<numChans` to subscript it.  Yet I get just `Float` when I do.

## EDIT:

hm, seems using `chans.advanced(by: a)` instead of subscripting fixed things

Comment: Firstly, check that if the `numChans` is 1

Answer (score 4):

Here is what I've found:

```
let arraySize = Int(buffer.frameLength)
let samples = Array(UnsafeBufferPointer(start: buffer.floatChannelData![0], count:arraySize))
```

This is assuming buffer is the name of your AVAudioPCMBuffer.

This way you can avoid pointers, which is likely much simpler. Now you can actually search through the data using a for loop.